# Определение CURRENT_TIMESTAMP лишнее?

Tags: база-данных, sql, mysql

Привет.Есть 2 запроса

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY COLUMN `column_name` TIMESTAMP NOT
NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY COLUMN `column_name` TIMESTAMP ;
```

Чем будут отличатся колонка
TIMESTAMP от

TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?
Вот мне стало интересно какая между ними разница?В обоих случаях по дефолту будет вставлено текущее время.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Разница есть**, она хорошо описана здесь

> [With neither DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP nor ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, it is the same as specifying both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP
);
```

т.е. если не задать DEFAULT то, при обновлении строки таблицы, если поле не было задано, оно превратится в текущую дату.

далее демонстрация эффекта:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9471e/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE a (id int,a TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE b (id int,a TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO a set id=1;

INSERT INTO b set id=1;

UPDATE a set a='2013-01-31';
UPDATE b set a='2013-01-31';

UPDATE a set id=2;
UPDATE b set id=2;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM a
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9471e/1/0)**:

```
| ID |                              A |
|----|--------------------------------|
|  2 | January, 31 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM b
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9471e/1/1)**:

```
| ID |                             A |
|----|-------------------------------|
|  2 | August, 31 2013 02:46:39+0000 |
```

Comment: Отлично. Не вижу пока смысла оставлять время суток обновления, если дата в прошлом(будущем).

Comment: ну например это не время обновления, а время регистрации :) можно даже одно поле без  default сделать, а второе - с (причем только в таком порядке, и при этом надо делать вот так:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5707

Answer (score 1):

Вы эти запросы один за другим выполняете?

Я плохо знаю MySQL, но могу предположить, что команда MODIFY меняет только то, что в ней указано, оставляя без изменений другие спецификации, в данном случае значение по умолчанию.

Comment: Наверно я неудачный привер пример.Чем будут отличатся колонка TIMESTAMP от TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP